# Ionic 3 App is not redirecting to specific page on notification click in foreground

Tags: angular, ionic3

It works perfectly when the app is open & receives notifications,It automatically redirect to specific page.But when the app is closed and received notifications then I click notifications, It does not redirect to page.It only show starts the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have an error in code on line 60

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask